# Speeding up numpy solve

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I am translating some code for a Gaussian Process regression from MATLAB to Python, and my Python version is much slower than the Matlab one. I discovered from the `cProfile` of my program that the bottleneck is Numpy's function `solve` from the Linalg library. This function is much, much slower than MATLAB's counterpart (i.e. `mldivide` or the `\` operator) and is called so frequently that the efficiency of the entire code is compromised. Is there something I can do to to speed up `solve`, or are there any better alternatives in Python?

Here's my np.show_config() in case it's helpful:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
  extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '- 
  I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
  extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
  define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_clapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
  extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
  extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
  define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

Comment: Can you show the result of `np.show_config()`? It sounds like you might be missing a fast linear algebra backend

Comment: @Eric Sure! These are the results from running the command on my Mac. However I ran the code on several other Linux/Macintosh machines and had the same problem

Comment: Yeah, are you sure *those* machines have a BLAS backend?

Comment: Can you also give some working example of your code, with timings you get on the particular problem so that anybody who reads this question can compare the results and give hints to improve performance?